# Restrict access to Azure blob from a specific referer / domain

Tags: wordpress, azure, blob, cdn, referer

I am using an Azure storage container (a blob) as a cdn for my website, hosted externally (on a digitalocean server). How can I restrict access to that blob from one domain only?

Scenario: images, audio and other files from the blob can be shown on my website (specific referer), but not accessed through a direct link (e.g. on social media...)

Thanks!